# Bootstrap icons not aligning inside buttons using IE8

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align the bootstrap 3 icons to center inside the buttons and they are aligning to the right, but only in IE 8. Here is my code:

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-circle btn-lg" type="button">
<i class="fa fa-trophy" style="font-size:30px;"></i>
</button>

I have tried adding margin-right:-5px to the style inside 
<i class="fa fa-trophy" style="font-size:30px;"></i>
```

but that does not work. This is what it looks like right now in IE8.

[image: trophy]

Comment: Please add your CSS too.

Comment: I did not add any additional css to this. The only css I know of would be the bootstap css but I cannot find the class fa fa-trophy to post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your CSS:
`.fa {position: relative; left: -5px\9}`

Comment: I tried it and it did not work. I tried removing the :after and it did in IE8 but now in firefox and Chrome it has shifted to the left.

Comment: I added a \0/ after the left:-5px..it is a hack but it seems to work for IE8 and then it the statement works in firefox and chrome. Is there a better way to do that? Should I have an IE8 CSS page and link to it from my page?

Comment: For that instance, I would use that type of IE hack to target. Usually I would use left: -5px\9 to target IE8